# .NET async, can a single thread time-slice between tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm trying to get a grasp on asynchronous programming in C#/.NET.  I read an article ([link](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs168/f12/handouts/async.pdf)) on Brown University's website for the cs168 course that defines asynchronous programming as interleaving tasks within the same thread. It says, "Now we can introduce the asynchronous model... In this model, the tasks are interleaved with one another, but in a single thread of control", and shows interleaving very clearly in a figure.  But I can't seem to get two tasks to interleave within the same thread in .NET.  Is there a way to do that?

I wrote some simple apps to try to test this theory, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.  The main program outputs to the screen every so often, using `Thread.Sleep()` to simulate work.  The asynchronous task does the same.  If multiple threads are used, the output is interleaved. But I'm trying to test on a single thread.

I have a WPF app that runs everything on the UI thread, but the task and main program always output sequentially. I create and start the task like this:

```
var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
var task = taskFactory.StartNew(workDelegate);
```

I have a console app that starts the task delegate using `Task.Run(workDelegate);`, but that runs them on different thread pool threads. I'm not sure how to make them both run on the same thread.  If I try the same approach I used in WPF I get a runtime InvalidOperationException, "The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple tasks won't automatically be interleaved on a single thread.  To do that, you have to specify the points in task code where the thread is allowed to cut over to another task.  You can do this via a mechanism like [`await Task.Yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield.aspx).  If you're running on a single thread, the thread will not be able to allow other work to progress unless it explicitly yields.

When you use your `TaskScheduler` to start every task, the message pump in WPF schedules each task to run on the UI thread, and they will run sequentially.

> I have a console app that starts the task delegate using Task.Run(workDelegate);, but that runs them on different thread pool threads. I'm not sure how to make them both run on the same thread.

You would need to install a custom `SynchronizationContext` into a thread which allowed you to post work to that thread.

Comment: Are you sure?  I ask because an article on Brown University's website for the cs168 course defines asynchronous programming as interleaving tasks within the same thread. It says, "Now we can introduce the asynchronous model, depicted in Figure 3... In this model, the tasks are interleaved with one another, but in a single thread of control", and shows interleaving very clearly in the figure. The article is linked in my question, but I should have pointed it out better (I'll update it). I'm surprised that .NET wouldn't support interleaving but still try to call it "asynchronous programming".

Comment: @JohnB Yes, I'm sure.  There are many definitions of "asynchrony" out there in the world.  They're defining asynchronous programming == cooperative multitasking, where "under the asynchronous model a task will continue to run until it explicitly relinquishes control to other tasks."  .NET is using the (much broader) term for asynchrony, similar to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony

Comment: @JohnB There's always some difficulty in language/terminology, especially when you start looking at academia vs. the rest of the world (for example, there's a huge difference between parallelism and concurrency in academia, but in most "real world" usage, they're treated as equivelent)

Comment: The terms are little bit overloaded and not 100% the same. Academic theoretical paper (even if it contains examples) is probably platform independent, while .NET is an actual platform. I have a bet that you can achieve what the publication says, you just have to find how the terms convert to the dictionary and toolset of .NET.

Comment: @JohnB That being said, the new async/await syntax does allow this, by their definition, via `await Task.Yield`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now that I understand the varying terminology, I see what I really wanted to know was if I can do cooperative multitasking in .NET. `await Task.Yield()` seems to be similar, but apparently requires that I pick points in code to relinquish control between tasks. There might not be convenient places, and for fine-grained switching I don't want to fill my code with yield calls. I had hoped .NET would time slice automatically, like it does with threads, but without the state or context switching overhead of another thread. It would be a great feature.

Comment: @JohnB That article, as referenced, basically says you'd need to do that.  The quote in my reply above is a reference from that article.  Typically, you'd use pre-emptive multitasking to handle asynchrony without this, which is the default in .NET (just use Task.Run, etc)

Comment: Okay, so I did understand that (it's the first time I've used yield).  So, it sounds like if I want single-threaded concurrency that's finer-grained than "whole task at a time", then I have to pick specific points in code to relinquish control using yield. I can live with that. I just wanted to be sure I understood.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run two concurrent Tasks in the same thread-pool thread. Each thread-pool thread can run one Task at a time. If you want to do two things in one thread, your options what I see now:
1. Combine the two things into one Task
2. Create two tasks and one would depend on the other one. SO in the end they would run sequentially after each other. By default it's not guaranteed that they would run in the same thread though, but you should not rely on that anyway.

It's not clear to me what you want to do. According to the books the UI and the thread of your WPF should do any heavy lifting number crunching work. It should take care of the UI and organize the worker threads/tasks. You would start operations in the background using async.

Comment: I just want to learn how asynchronous programming works. There's an academic article I read (linked in my question) that specifically defines asynchronous programming as interleaving within a thread. I should have pointed that out better in my question and I'll update it now.

Comment: I don't like the document you linked.The main idea of the Task Parallel framework, is that you should worry about how the execution happens if you have some concurrent tasks. You just define your tasks, define dependencies between them, and then let the system do the scheduling and work. You use the framework as a tool to compose your logical dependencies. It's another level if Threads need communication between each other, that can be done too.

Comment: I agree about only defining tasks/dependencies and letting the scheduler handle the rest.  I was just thinking it would time slice concurrent tasks together, as it does with threads, but without the overhead of using another thread.