# Is it safe to use lock() with Tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I read here:

[.NET async, can a single thread time-slice between tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549771/net-async-can-a-single-thread-time-slice-between-tasks)

that, unless you explicitly use async/await, tasks will not "time-slice" on the same thread in the backend thread-pool. Is this guaranteed? Or merely a side effect of the current implementation of the TPL?

If not guaranteed, it would cause problems with using `lock()`:

Consider two Tasks which access a method that `locks` on a full SerialPort transaction (send a message and receive, or timeout) before releasing. If time-slicing occurs on the same thread and the SerialPort access is slow enough, the `lock` would fail to do its job (letting both calls through, because they are technically on the same thread).

Comment: Since you don't normally `lock` around external calls whatever behavior is there should not be problem for real code...

Comment: Yes, its guaranteed because the task scheduler (even custom) will wait for a given task execution to yield or return. You physically cannot run two bodies of code at the same time on the same thread without the task yielding to the scheduler.

Comment: Note that this question is about raw TPL code as it does not apply to `async`/`await` code - you can't have `lock` around `await` as you get error "The 'await' operator cannot be used in the body of a lock statement" trying to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you don't do anything that makes (some parts of) your code execute on another thread (`await`, `Task.Run()`, `Task.ContinueWith()`, `Thread`, …), then it's safe to use `lock` or another thread-based synchronization mechanism.

One possible exception is if you have a custom `TaskScheduler` (e.g. `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`) and you somehow make that scheduler try to execute more `Task`s while your `Task` is still executing (e.g. something like `Application.DoEvents()`). In that case, your `Task` still won't move to another thread, but it may be paused while another `Task` executes on the same thread. But this situation should be exceedingly rare.